# Why do workers die from memory problems when using multiprocessing in Python to do LCA calculations?

Tags: python-multiprocessing, brightway

I am having an issue using multiprocessing in Python in order to calculate LCA results for all functional units in the ecoinvent v3.2 database for several iterations.

The code is the following :

```
for worker_id in range(CPUS):

    # Create child processes that can work apart from parent process
    child = mp.Process(target=worker_process, args=(projects.current, output_dir, worker_id, activities, ITERATIONS, status))
    workers.append(child)
    child.start()
print(workers)

while any(i.is_alive() for i in workers):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    while not status.empty():
        # Flush queue of progress reports
        worker, completed = status.get()
        progress[worker] = completed
    progbar.update(sum(progress.values()))
progbar.finish()
```

Defining the `worker_process` function as follows :

```
def worker_process(project, output_dir, worker_id, activities, iterations, progress_queue):

# Project is string; project name in Brightway2
# output_dir is a string
# worker_id is an integer
# activities is a list of dictionaries
# iterations is an integer
# progress_queue is a Queue where we can report progress to parent process

projects.set_current(project, writable=False)

lca = DirectSolvingPVLCA(activities[0])
lca.load_data()
samples = np.empty((iterations, lca.params.shape[0]))
supply_arrays = np.empty((iterations, len(activities), len(lca.product_dict)))

for index in range(iterations):

    lca.rebuild_all()
    samples[index, :] = lca.sample
    lca.decompose_technosphere()  
    for act_index, fu in enumerate(activities):
        lca.build_demand_array(fu)
        supply_arrays[index, act_index, :] = lca.solve_linear_system()
    progress_queue.put((worker_id, index))
```

The observed problems are :

1. For more than two workers, all except two die immediately from a `MemoryError` (see below).
2. For the two surviving workers, the code seems to work fine for 10, 100 or 5000 functional units, but as we ask for all FUs, it breaks down and runs into the same `MemoryError`.

This `MemoryError` occurs for each *X* process :

```
    Process Process-X: 
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
      File "C:\bw2-python\envs\bw2\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in_bootstrap 
        self.run()    
      File "C:\bw2-python\envs\bw2\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run   
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   
      File "C:\test\Do all the calculations.py", line 49, in worker_process 
        supply_arrays = np.empty((iterations, len(activities), len(lca.product_dict))) 
    MemoryError
```

My questions are :

- Why does this occur ?
- How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of memory because you are using too much memory.

When you allocate a new array using:

```
np.empty((iterations, len(activities), len(lca.product_dict)))
```

And `activities` and `lca.product_dict` each have a length of, say, 10.000, you are using 10.000 * 10.000 * 8 (assuming your default float is 64 bits, or 8 bytes) = 800 MB of ram per iteration and per worker process.

An easy solution is to work on a server with lots of RAM.

Alternatives to creating these large arrays in memory include:

- Using [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/) or [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/)
- Using [Numpy's `memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

In either case, you will need to test the most efficient ways of writing and reading data for your specific workflow and OS carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Seems that converting data into half-precision float in numpy files worked !
But I continue to examine which is the best option to optimise time and memory.